# Core Data Beginner

Tags: iphone, relationship, core-data

does someone know where i can find example to do that case ?
 2 entities : Catalogue of books and Books.
One relation to-Many between. I found many tuto to explain how to make appears A book of selected catalogue (tableview) but none for a "double" tableview which is simple i suppose.
The first tableview will present all the book's catalogue and after selection, a second tableview will list all the books of a selected catalogue.(A last selection could finaly give datas of the book)

I try to understand how to make link from book to catalogue with the relation. (with nspredicate?)

culd you give me a concrete example(or tuto link) to help me understand ?

Answer (score 2):

Begginer here too, but the Sample Code [Core Data Recipes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) seems to be pretty similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Following tutorials I found useful

**Swift**

1. [Code.tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-25068)
2. [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

**Objecive C**

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started
2. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html
3. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_OS_Core_Data_Tutorial
4. http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php